# Patterns Union Chain of Responsability, Factory Method, Strategy

Tags: design-patterns

I want know if is possible put together  three patterns: FactoryMethod, Chain of Responsability and Strategy Pattern. For this I would want use the Chain of Responsability client class than factory of FactoryMethod and, too, than context of the pattern strategy. Is posible this and appropriate?

For example in the diagram the class Uno and Strategy are concrete Hanlder of Chain of responsability pattern. But, too, the abstract class strategy is a strategy class in the pattern "Strategy". The Uno class is a abstract class to FactoryMethod Pattern.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself if the patterns you want to use in your problem makes it easier to solve it. If you specify in what scenario they are applied, probably you can get a concrete answer.

Comment: without scenary, is this posible?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is a temptation to use patterns just because it's 'cool' and patterns can make code look more 'professional'. I suggest you to start with KISS and YAGNI, then after you have your first sketch you can think more about 'patterns glory'. Don't add it without a reason, it will only make your code less readable.

Comment: I don't use the patterns because these are "cool". I want know If is posible use the patterns in this form. The scenary is important but I want know if is this posible without modify significantly the pattern used.

Comment: imo you will never get an answer to your question, because patterns are not supposed to be used like that. Patterns are the language that helps to interact with other people in a more efficient way. You can transfer information to another person faster if you will use the language of patterns. You can easier 'decode' other person's code if  this person used patterns language. But they are not supposed to be a building blocks for software at the first place. If you are constraining yourself with the pattern - it's not very effective way to build an app.

Comment: It usually works better it you building your app, and in the process of building it - you recognizing some patterns that you know, but not the other way. If you go other way - pattern most likely will 'lock' you in a 'box', and you will tend to be less flexible and creative when building your architecture.

Comment: However, by saying that I must admit that it's useful to think using patterns language as well. It's speeds you up sometimes. Just don't let those patterns take over your creativity and non-standard approaches. Please share your specific domain if it's possible.